# Why is the first "if" activated by itself when the second "else if" condition is met?

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox, addeventlistener, boolean-operations

Basically, when the condition "`event.target === checkbox && active`" is met, the value of '`active`' becomes "`false`". Therefore, the next click on the checkbox will satisfy the first condition "`event.target === checkbox && !active`", and that's what I want. However, what happens is that once the condition "`event.target === checkbox && active`" is met, and the code block is executed, the code block of the first "`if`" statement is also automatically executed. As a result, '`active`' acquires the value "`false`" and then immediately regains the value of "`true`" again. This essentially prevents unchecking the checkbox if you click on it, which is something I don't want. Do you know how to prevent this from happening, and why does it happen in the first place?

There is the code:

```
function toggleSelectionMenu(checkbox, menu) {
  let active = false;
  document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target === checkbox && !active) {
      checkbox.checked = true;
      menu.style.display = 'block';
      active = true;
      console.log(active);

    } else if (event.target !== checkbox && active || event.target === checkbox && active) {
      checkbox.checked = false;
      menu.style.display = 'none';
      active = false;
      console.log(active);
    }
  });
}
```

What I want is that the first click on the checkbox does what is described in the first "`if`" statement, and that the next click within the DOM executes what is stated in the following code block, regardless of whether the click is on the same checkbox or any other part of the DOM.

Comment: Just a note... `event.target !== checkbox && active || event.target === checkbox && active` is simply `active`.

Comment: are you calling `toggleSelectionMenu` more than once?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, but with different parameters:

` toggleSelectionMenu(langBtn, langMenu); 
toggleSelectionMenu(cipherModeBtn, cipherMenu);`

I just deleted the second call but it doesn't work neither

Comment: @PM77-1 Oh thanks! I didn't notice that optimization at all

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Because of that "optimization", when you click on a different checkbox, you may toggle the active state of this checkbox.

Comment: Why are you adding the event listener to `document` instead of `checkbox`? This doesn't seem to be a situation where event delegation is needed.

Comment: Why do you need the `active` variable? Just use `if (checkbox.checked)`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your comments. I tried to use a snippet after your recommendation but it doesn't work like my code :/. And I use `document` because I want that the next click in DOM in general (including the checkbox inself) causes the `checkbox` to stop being checked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `else if` condition is true whether or not `event.target` is `checkbox`. So when you click on an active checkbox, you'll toggle *all* the active checkboxes.

Separate the checking of `event.target` and `active`.

```
function toggleSelectionMenu(checkbox, menu) {
  let active = false;
  document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (!(event.target.nodeName == 'INPUT' && event.target.type == 'checkbox')) {
      // clicking outside any checkbox, uncheck it
      checkbox.checked = false;
      menu.style.display = 'none';
      active = false;
      console.log(active);
      return;
    }

    // not clicking on this checkbox, ignore
    if (event.target !== checkbox) {
      return;
    }

    // toggle the checkbox
    if (!active) {
      checkbox.checked = true;
      menu.style.display = 'block';
      active = true;
      console.log(active);
    } else {
      checkbox.checked = false;
      menu.style.display = 'none';
      active = false;
      console.log(active);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: That solves the main issue of my concern, but now, if I click anywhere else in the DOM other than the checkbox, the checkbox does not remove its 'checked' attribute :/

Comment: If there are multiple checkboxes, and you click outside all of them, how do you know which one to uncheck?

Comment: I want to uncheck all of them. On the other hand, "checkbox" is only a parameter and I put the specifically checkbox that I want in the function as a parameter. (In my case, langBtn and cipherModeBtn in my code are the checkboxes that I want to operate into the function)

Comment: This gets tricky. The problem is that when you click on a different checkbox, you're also clicking outside this checkbox.

Comment: I've updated the code, I think this should work. Could you update the question with a [mre] that I could add my code to for testing?